# Access to a value for my css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple question, but I didn't find anything on gg
How can I access to a value (:color in this case) which is a string(ex:"#E0ED44"). And use it to define the background of my div ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use this simple line : style="background-color:<%=post.color%>;"